# Unable to Compile KAA C++ SDK

Tags: c++, kaa

While compiling C++ SDK I am getting the following error
**

- ERROR LOGS

**
fatal error: kaa/gen/EndpointGen.hpp: No such file or directory
[  1%] Building CXX object kaa/CMakeFiles/kaacpp.dir/impl/event/registration/EndpointRegistrationManager.cpp.o
In file included from /home/vidhi/Projects/Kaa/kaaCppApp/kaa/kaa/channel/ITransportConnectionInfo.hpp:25:0,
                 from /home/vidhi/Projects/Kaa/kaaCppApp/kaa/kaa/KaaDefaults.hpp:28,
                 from /home/vidhi/Projects/Kaa/kaaCppApp/kaa/kaa/event/registration/EndpointRegistrationManager.hpp:20,
                 from /home/vidhi/Projects/Kaa/kaaCppApp/kaa/impl/event/registration/EndpointRegistrationManager.cpp:17:
/home/vidhi/Projects/Kaa/kaaCppApp/kaa/kaa/channel/TransportProtocolId.hpp:22:35: fatal error: kaa/gen/EndpointGen.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "kaa/gen/EndpointGen.hpp"
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [kaa/CMakeFiles/kaacpp.dir/impl/event/registration/EndpointRegistrationManager.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [kaa/CMakeFiles/kaacpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Manually I place EndpointGen.hpp file but again while compiling it's giving the same error for different file. Later I found files inside kaa/CMakeFiles/kaacpp.dir/impl/ were missing.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of KAA are you taking ?

Comment: This issue was resolved in v2.0.0 by adding `compile-client-cpp` option to the maven goals when compiling Kaa.

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I am using kaa-0.10.0.

Comment: and also in github I could see max version is v0.10.0, I could not find v2.0.0. Could you please help if I am wrong.

Comment: http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/APP-375?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: I might be that it is about to release

Comment: Thank You Milind its working now.

Comment: You can mark the answer as `accepted` so that other users to solve this issue using this question thread

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved in `v2.0.0` by adding `compile-client-cpp` option to the maven goals when compiling Kaa.

See the [reference](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/APP-375?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) for this.